# pass parameters to pdf metadata in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I'm trying to pass data to metadata setup of the `.pdf` file with this code  but its brings me an error, when passing the data

```
\def\author#1{\gdef\insertauthor{#1}\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\title#1{\gdef\inserttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#1}}
\def\firstsupervisor#1{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\def\secondsupervisor#1{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\def\institution#1{\gdef\insertinstitution{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\insertdegree{#1}}
\def\faculty#1{\gdef\insertfaculty{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\insertdepartment{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\insertsubmitdate{#1}}
\def\keywords#1{\gdef\insertkeywords{#1}}
\submitdate{\number\the\year}

\RequirePackage[final,breaklinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,
    pdftitle    = {\inserttitle},
    pdfkeywords = {\insertkeywords},
    pdfauthor   = {\textcopyright\ \insertauthor},
    pdfcreator  = {\LaTeX\ with package \flqq hyperref\frqq},
    pdfproducer = {pdfeTeX-0.\the\pdftexversion\pdftexrevision}
}
\RequirePackage{hypcap}
```

the error says `Undefined control sequence. }`

Comment: By the time of setting content like `pdftitle`, is `\inserttitle` defined? Probably not.

Comment: when I use  `\title{the title}` in other spaces I can get the title with `\inserttitle` and it works fine on all places except here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\hypersetup` comes into action before `\title` is used, so it tries to get grip of an undefined command `\inserttitle` at that time. The same is true for `\insertauthor` and `\insertkeywords`. LaTeX is complaining on `\inserttitle` because its the first of those three commands used in `\hypersetup`.

Since `\hypersetup` is no preamble-restricted command, it can be used more than once and even in the document body, if needed.

I suggest to use the `\title` etc. commands to automatically insert the relevant data. This works, as long as `\title` etc. are not used before `hyperref` is loaded and preset `\hypersetup` only with basically-non-author/document content relevant data

Apparently the shown fragment is from a `.cls` or `.sty` file, I've built a document around it, wrapping `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around the various `\def....` commands there.

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter

\def\author#1{\gdef\insertauthor{#1}\gdef\@author{#1}\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ #1}}}
\def\title#1{\gdef\inserttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#1}\hypersetup{pdftitle={#1}}}
\def\firstsupervisor#1{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\def\secondsupervisor#1{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\def\institution#1{\gdef\insertinstitution{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\insertdegree{#1}}
\def\faculty#1{\gdef\insertfaculty{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\insertdepartment{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\insertsubmitdate{#1}}
\def\keywords#1{\gdef\insertkeywords{#1}\hypersetup{pdfkeywords={#1}}}
\submitdate{\number\the\year}

\makeatother

\RequirePackage[final,breaklinks,bookmarks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,
%    pdftitle    = {\inserttitle},%
%    pdfkeywords = {\insertkeywords},
%    pdfauthor   = {\textcopyright\ \insertauthor},%
    pdfcreator  = {\LaTeX\ with package \flqq hyperref\frqq},
    pdfproducer = {pdfeTeX-0.\the\pdftexversion\pdftexrevision}
}


\title{Theory on Brontosaurs}
\author{Miss Ann Elk}
\keywords{Brontosaurs,Monty Python,LaTeX is fun}

\begin{document}
\maketitle% 

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Please note, that `\maketitle` redefines `\title`, and `\author` etc. in many classes to become effectively nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first call to `\hypersetup` where you want to set the PDF document properties requires all of the macros to exist, otherwise there you're receive an error message. My suggestion would therefore be to make sure all of these new `\insert...` macros exist. Do so by adding

```
\providecommand{\insertauthor}{}
\providecommand{\inserttitle}{}
\providecommand{\insertfirstsupervisor}{}
\providecommand{\insertsecondsupervisor}{}
\providecommand{\insertinstitution}{}
\providecommand{\insertdegree}{}
\providecommand{\insertfaculty}{}
\providecommand{\insertdepartment}{}
\providecommand{\insertsubmitdate}{}
\providecommand{\insertkeywords}{}
```

to your preamble. Secondly, delay the setting of PDF document properties until the end of the document using

```
\AtEndDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle    = \inserttitle,
    pdfkeywords = \insertkeywords,
    pdfauthor   = \insertauthor
  }
}
```