# hyperref’s pdfusetitle option fails with authblk

Tags: hyperref, metadata, authblk

I would like to use the functionalities provided by the package `authblk` and get automatically the right author metadata in my PDF. Normally, the `pdfusetitle` option of `hyperref` sets the right title and author metadata. With `authblk`, however, this works for the title but not for authors. I suppose it’s because `authblk` changes the “author” mechanism.

Can I patch this easily? Or is there a package similar to `authblk` that is compatible with this functionality of `hyperref`?

Even better if the patch also works when multiple authors are given, in which case the pdf metadata should show the author names separated by commas.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates the incompatibility. If `authblk` is loaded before `hyperref`, and with `pdfusetitle`, loading `hyperref` fails with `Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@author`. If loading `authblk` after `hyperref` (as illustrated here), the document gets compiled, but contains no author metadata. When uncommenting the `hypersetup` block, the author metadata reads: `immediate LaTeX Warning: No given.`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}

%\makeatletter
%\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\@author}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{Myself}

Content.

\end{document}
```

Here is an example of my current usage. I would like to get rid of the redundant `\hypersetup` part.

```
\title{The title}
\author{Firstname Lastname}
\author{Second author}
\affil{First affiliation\\
    \href{mailto:firstname.fastname@affiliation}{firstname.fastname@affiliation}
}
\author{Name3}
\affil{Second affiliation}
\makeatletter
    \hypersetup{
        pdfauthor={Firstname Lastname, Second author, Name3}
    }
\makeatother
\maketitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an `xpatch` solution. The list of authors is stored in a separate macro which can be used by `\hypersetup`. This list is constructed by adding a call to a helper macro at the start of the `\author` command from `authblk`. This uses argument `#2` because `#1` is used for the optional footnote marker.

A conditional is used to check if the current author is the first in the list (then the list is defined as the current name) or a further entry (add a comma and the current entry to the list).

If you put the `\hypersetup` in the preamble then the list is not yet constructed, and the pdf author metadata will be empty. However, following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254516/ you can delay the execution of the `\hypersetup` command until the end of the document with `\AtEndDocument`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% add a macro call to the start of \author
\xpretocmd{\author}{\addhrauthor{#2}}{}{}
% define boolean for list construction and set to true
\newif\iffirstauthor
\firstauthortrue
\newcommand{\addhrauthor}[1]{%
% first entry: author list is defined as the current author, set boolean to false
\iffirstauthor%
\newcommand{\hrauthor}{#1}\firstauthorfalse%
% further entries: add to list
\else%
\xapptocmd{\hrauthor}{, #1}{}{}%
\fi
}
\AtEndDocument{ % delayed call for \hypersetup in preamble
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\hrauthor}}
}
\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{Firstname 1 Lastname 1}
\author{Second author}
\affil{First affiliation\\
   \href{mailto:firstname.fastname@affiliation}{firstname.fastname@affiliation}
}
\author{Name3}
\affil{Second affiliation}

%\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\hrauthor}} % direct call after setting the author names

\maketitle
Content.

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! One problem: when I put the patch commands in a block (inside an `\iftoggle`), they do not work. I’d like to patch only conditionally, because I do not necessarily need `authblk`. Any idea? Also, I’d like to [hide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466229/hyperref-option-pdfusetitle-with-thanks#comment1171930_466229) all of this in the preamble (thus avoid `hypersetup` after the titling part), is it possible?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux the only thing the patch does is to store the list of authors in a separate macro. Therefore you can just leave it in when you don't use `authblk`, then it will patch the regular `\author` command instead (without any effects on the command itself).

Comment: See edit for the issue of putting commands in the preamble.

Comment: Indeed it does not work conditionally with a toggle (I don't know why) but it does work with a classic if-else-fi (similar to the `\iffirstauthor` construct).