# Code seems to have no effect when inside `iftoggle`

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471297) answer I have been suggested to patch `hyperref`’s automatic pdfauthor metadata handling mechanism as follows. The goal is to have PDF metadata work with `authblk` and multiple authors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtoggle{patchhref}
\toggletrue{patchhref}
%\iftoggle{patchhref}{
    \xpretocmd{\author}{\addhrauthor{#2}}{}{}
    \newif\iffirstauthor
    \firstauthortrue
    \newcommand{\addhrauthor}[1]{%
        \iffirstauthor%
            \newcommand{\hrauthor}{#1}\firstauthorfalse%
        \else%
            \xapptocmd{\hrauthor}{, #1}{}{}%
        \fi
    }
    \AtEndDocument{
        \hypersetup{pdfauthor={\hrauthor}}
    }
%}{
%}

\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{Firstname 1 Lastname 1}
\author{Second author}
\affil{First affiliation\\
   \href{mailto:firstname.fastname@affiliation}{firstname.fastname@affiliation}
}
\author{Name3}
\affil{Second affiliation}

\maketitle
Content.

\end{document}
```

I have added the `iftoggle` thing, it was not in the original answer. When not using `iftoggle`, it works. But, when using `iftoggle` (uncomment the three related lines to try it out), it fails when reaching the end of the document with `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \hrauthor`. As if the commands that define `hrauthor` had not been executed. But the part about `\AtEndDocument` does get executed. According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471277/hyperref-s-pdfusetitle-option-fails-with-authblk/471297?noredirect=1#comment1196796_471297) comment, replacing `iftoggle` with legacy `if` construct works.

How can I make this patch work conditionally, using `iftoggle`, the [preferred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5896) mechanism for conditional toggling?

Comment: You can't. The patching fails due to the `#2` (and if you had added e.g. a `\fail` command you would have get a suitable error message `\xpretocmd{\author}{\addhrauthor{#2}}{}{\fail}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `\iftoggle` per se but with category codes (catcodes). When TeX scans a token for the first time, its category code is "frozen", i.e. TeX remembers what it was when it was first read. In your case, the `#` is the culprit.

`\iftoggle{patchhref}` expands to something equivalent to `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`:

```
\newcommand\@firstoftwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\@secondoftwo[2]{#2}
```

This scans the next two groups and removes the second one. All the catcodes in the first group are frozen in the process. `#` usually has category code `6` and some care is needed when patching commands with `#`. `\xpretocmd` tries to take care of this, but if the `#` has already been scanned, this fails.

You can work around this problem by defining

```
{\catcode`#=11\relax
    \gdef\fixauthor{\xpretocmd{\author}{\addhrauthor{#2}}{}{}}%
}
```

before your `\iftoggle` and replacing the `\xpatchcmd` line with `\fixauthor`.

Comment: Thanks! Missing one `}` at the end of the `\gdef` line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the `\addrauthor` in the toggle part: you have to write the code anyway.

The problem with doing the patch in the argument to a command can be solved in various ways, the simplest one is to use standard conditionals.

Here I suggest an easier version of the `\addhrauthor` macro with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch,xparse}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_oc_hrauthor_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\addhrauthor}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_oc_hrauthor_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hrauthor}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_oc_hrauthor_seq {,~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifpatchhref
%\patchhreftrue

\ifpatchhref
  \xpretocmd{\author}{\addhrauthor{#2}}{}{}
  \AtEndDocument{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\hrauthor}}}
\fi


\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{Firstname 1 Lastname 1}
\author{Second author}
\affil{First affiliation\\
   \href{mailto:firstname.fastname@affiliation}{firstname.fastname@affiliation}
}
\author{Name3}
\affil{Second affiliation}

\maketitle
Content.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point about the definitions out of the toggle. For the rest, using a standard conditional (`ifpatchhref`) is not great in my case: I use a global toggle (to separate the presentation and article cases) and use heavily `iftoggle` in various parts of my preamble. I’d like to patch the author mechanism iff that same toggle is in presentation mode. Now, either I have to completely get rid of `iftoggle` and replace by a standard conditional everywhere; or I have to use `ifpatchhref` (set equal to the toggle) especially for this, a strange exception that will reduce clarity of the code.

Comment: Hard to choose one answer for acceptance. I ended up accepting @schtandard’s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475530) because it lets me stick to the toggle mechanism I prefer. But I actually implemented parts of both answers.