# Clash between hyperxmp and authblk

Tags: hyperref, authblk, hyperxmp

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
some text
\end{document}
```

This leads to multiple "token not allowed in PDF string" warnings. This can be reproduced without the `pdfcomment` package, but it certainly makes things much worse.

I believe something happens when processing metadata; a related situation occurs [hyperref’s pdfusetitle option fails with authblk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471277/hyperref-s-pdfusetitle-option-fails-with-authblk), but the situation isn't exactly the same.

Comment: Try loading hyperref the last package.

Comment: @hesham I have tested and it seems that with any order of these four package the problem persists.  This being said, I have been using the current sequence to mitigate conflicts with `xr` and other packages.

Comment: There is a warning, but is there a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the author for the pdf metadata with `pdfauthor`. Then hyperxmp will no longer try to get it from the `\author` command which `authblk` redefines in an way quite unsuitable for pdf metadata:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[pdfauthor={Author}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. so if there is a more elegant way to get the features `authblk` providing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.