# Hyperref PDF metadata doesn't add author

Tags: hyperref, metadata

I've been trying to update the metadata of my PDF and I've encountered some problems. I loaded `hyperref` in the last place on my document, but I tried to put it in different places.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-nd},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\def\@title{#1}}
\newcommand{\tipus}[1]{\def\@tipus{#1}}
\newcommand{\actual}[2]{\def\@curs{#1}\def\@semestre{#2}}
\newcommand{\professor}[2]{\def\@nom{#1}\def\@cognom{#2}}
\newcommand{\resum}[1]{\def\@resum{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[1]{\def\@degree{#1}}
\newcommand{\titleback}[1]{\def\@titleback{#1}}
\newcommand{\classification}[1]{\def\@classification{#1}}
\makeatother

\author{Mario}
\title{Càlcul Diferencial en Diverses Variables}
\actual{2022-2023}{Cinquè}
\tipus{Apunts}
\professor{Dr. A}{B}
\degree{Matemàtiques}
\resum{Aquesta assignatura tracta les funcions reals de diverses variables reals, treballant les nocions de límit, continuïtat i diferenciabilitat d'aquestes funcions.}
\classification{00-01, 97I40, 97I60, 97N40}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter%
  \hypersetup{%
    linkbordercolor={lightgray},%
    urlbordercolor={darkgray},%
    citebordercolor={lightgray},%
    pdfinfo={%
    Title={\@title},%
    Author={\@author},%
    Subject={\@degree},%
    Producer={pdfTeX},%
    Creator={\@author},%
    Keywords={\@tipus},%
    }%
}
\makeatother%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{.6cm}
Hello
\end{document}
```

When I get info on the generated PDF, the author field doesn't even appear. The same happens with the keywords. I have also tried to assign `Author` to an immutable (like `s`, for example). Nothing has worked so far. Assume that I've tried everything in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254422/pass-parameters-to-pdf-metadata-in-hyperref), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26529/how-can-i-generate-pdf-metadata-from-latex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/make-hyperref-take-pdfinfo-from-title-and-author).

**Note**: checking the `hyperxmp` documentation, in particular, the complete example section, it would suffice to include `hyperxmp` right before `hyperref`.

[image: Photo of the output]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you set the `\author` in your document?

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't appear, with the copy-paste I must have left it out. I will update the MWE. It still doesn't work (both author and keywords).

Comment: More like the `\@author` variable. It seems to be empty.

Comment: But it isn't. The `Creator` field catches the value correctly. I will leave a photo.

Comment: seems to be caused by the doclicense package. Do you need this package?

Comment: You are right!! But, yes, it would be preferable... would a workaround be possible?

Comment: Don't dump simply your preamble on us. Make a shorter example. Remove all the package not related to the problem.

Comment: Please follow this guide for MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: As I think you will understand, until half hour ago I didn't know what was the incompatibility. I will remove "all the package not related to the problem".

Comment: sure, but if you had tried to make a concise example then you would have found out much earlier that the doclicense package is involved  and could have ask a much better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doclicense` loads the `hyperxmp` package which adds XMP-metadata to the PDF.

As is described in the `hyperxmp` documentation on page 13, it suppresses some entries in the info dictionary to make pdf/A validators more happy. You can avoid this suppression by using the `keeppdfinfo` option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\author{Mario}
\title{Càlcul Diferencial en Diverses Variables}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter%
  \hypersetup{%
    pdfinfo={%
    Title={\@title},%
    Author={\@author},%
    Subject={subject},%
    Producer={pdfTeX},%
    Creator={\@author},%
    Keywords={Apunts},%    
    },%
    keeppdfinfo %keep info entries
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

Hello
\end{document}
```

In PDF 2.0 the info dictionary is deprecated in favor of XMP-metadata and in texlive 2023 pdftex will have an option to suppress it altogether.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working now.